# ThreeJS - light doesn't illuminate surface unless behind?

Tags: three.js, lighting

I've got a collada model in ThreeJs with a simple point light that follows the mouse. When the light is *behind* the model, its front face is illuminated:

### object with the light behind it:

[image: object with the light behind it]

But when the light is in front of it, only the sides receive light/specularity:

### object with the light in front:

[image: object with the light in front]

I'm losing a whole lotta hair over why on earth it does this. The normals are pointing the correct direction, everything else seems fine.

The materials are all just white lamberts, if that helps at all.

Anyone encountered this?

Comment: What is your `material.side` setting? Did you try with material set to `THREE.DoubleSide`?

Comment: check the normals of your object

Comment: Cheers @Wilt, I've tried with and without doubleside - doesn't seem to make a difference.